# Custo Médio SQL

Tags: sql

Olá.
Preciso apresentar o o custo médio, o menor custo e o maior custo de todos os produtos e apresentar ainda o total de produtos verificados.
A tabela que eu tenho é essa: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como eu gero isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
select max(custoun)      as maior_custo_unitario,
       avg(custoun)      as custo_unitario_medio,
       min(custoun)      as menor_custo_unitario,
       count(codprod)    as qtde_total_produtos
 from nome_tabela
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Raphael!!

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudar :)